# How to uninstall Paper icon theme in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, themes, debian, icon-themes

I installed the paper icon theme from the .zip file downloaded from

[Paper-Icon-Theme](https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme)

How can I uninstall it now?

Comment: How did you install it to begin with? If you just extracted the theme in your ~/.icons directory you can just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based od `install-icon-theme.sh`, it's in standard location...

here:

```
/usr/share/icons/
```

or

```
~/.local/share/icons/
```

just delete the folder containing the icon theme (folder should be called "Paper")